# UIView stick to finger?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

My problem is this. The user can hold over a specific image on a grid, once the user holds the image for 2 seconds another view pops up above it. Now i need the program to work as since the users finger is still down on the screen, the newly created view will move with the finger. As it works now is that the user will have to remove their finger and place it back on the screen in order for the view to move with it. Any ideas people?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to detect the initial press, you can also use it to track movement, because it keeps calling your gesture action method until the user lifts their finger.

Comment: I do already implement UILongPressGestureRecognizer. It works like this. LongPressOnVie then it uses a NSNotification to call to the view controller to create the new view above the one i am pressing.It creates the view but i am not able to move the view with out removing my finger and pressing down again

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways you could probably do it. One that comes to mind is the manage the touch events through the view controller itself. This will require you to implement `-canBecomeFirstResponder` and of course the `touches[Began|Moved|Ended|Cancelled]:withEvent:` methods.

Another way,  if you are using an `UIImageView` to manage and display the individual images, you could subclass it and handle the touch events through that. In this case, you wouldn't actually create a new `UIView` for tracking the drag, you could just use `NSAffineTransform` to give it the appearance of "popping out" and continue to track the location with the same view object. Once the touch ends, apply the identify transform to restore its normal size. Transforms are animatable.

**EDIT**

In your view controller implementation, besides implementing the touch methods described above, do the following to actually receive touch events in the controller:

```
@implementation MyViewController

...

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;  // Default for UIResponder is NO
}

...

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    ...
    [self becomeFirstResponder];  // ensures view controller receives touch events
}

...

@end
```

Comment: I have all my code already written in all the touches methods so i will have to go that route. What do you mean my implement canBecomeFirstResponder, according to the docs its only a property that returns True or False

Comment: If you want your view controller to be a first responder (i.e. receive the touch events), you need to implement - `(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder { return YES; }` (the default is to return `NO`). In your view controller's `-viewDidAppear:` method, add `[self becomeFirstResponder];` to make it the first responder.